# Deleting session variables after the user logout in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, session, logout

I have set session variables using, 
sessionStorage.setItem('Username', this.state.username);

How to delete values of session variables after the user logout?

Comment: ``storage.removeItem(keyName);`` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: Please share your code where you handle the user logout click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need do is to call `removeItem` with the `key` that you used to set `sessionStorage`. The APIs are clearly mentioned in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

```
// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('Username');
```